# Upsert Only inserts and does not update the existing field

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I am trying to add attendances to the attendance table and if attendance of the give date and student id is already in the table I need to update the attendance type.

But the upsert is only inserting and it does not ever update.

```php
SmStudentAttendance::upsert($studentRows, ['student_id', 'attendance_date'], ['attendance_type']);
```

Comment: Please share more details

Answer (score 2):

It's too late but it worked for me. Try this in a migration:

```php
$table->unique(['student_id', 'attendance_date']);
```

Or you can add unique constraints to the columns in phpmyadmin (or a similar tool)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 1):

upsert works exactly like

`on duplicate key update on MySQL`

which needs a unique constraint violation to update instead of an insert.

So check if you have such a violation, directly in the database.

Also you can read more about with an example for example  at https://www.amitmerchant.com/insert-or-update-multiple-records-using-upsert-in-laravel8/

Comment: I am giving two columns to identify but it doesnt work.

Comment: as i wrote in my answer, you need a violation of a unique key which includes a primary key, if student_id is neiterh you can't use upsert

Comment: Did you solved it ? I am facing same issue.I added unique(['column1','column2', 'column3']) to identify uniqueness. but it doesnt work.it keeps on inserting.In django its easy by adding unique_together('column1,column2,,,,)

Comment: make a show create table and see if there is a unique key, if tghere is you didn't read the link i provided, you need not only the unique keys, which will not update, but also at last a  column that can get the new value, with thre uniqe column your query doesn't make any sense